# Checking the iPhone GPS accuracy/position when starting an app

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I'm trying to code an app that uses GPS. When it starts running, it shows a screen with some informations, when the GPS accuracy detected is lower than a certain bias the app can become operative. In normal conditions (when gps accuracy detected is enough) is a tabbed bar app and GPS can be switched off.
I have already made some "experiments" with GPS and the CoreLocation framework but the difficulty for me is that I don't know how to act in AppDelegate to do what I just described or if there is a different technique to adopt.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest setting a rootViewController in your UIWindow with some kind of "determining your location, please wait" message, etc. Have a manager class (I'd prefer it as a singleton to make it easy to access) as the delegate for the CLLocationManager. When your app starts, your AppDelegate starts your CLLocationManagerDelegate class so it can find the location. When sufficient accuracy is achieved the AppDelegate is notified (it can observe the CLLocationManagerDelegate or be told manually) the UIWindow's rootViewController is then set to the "normal" ViewController (UITabbarController or whatever you want). This can then acces the same CLLocationManagerDelegate class and present what you want with the information.